# Is there a schematic symbol for a supercapacitor?

Tags: capacitor, schematics, symbol, supercapacitor

Is there a schematic symbol for a supercapacitor, as distinct from smaller polarized capacitors?

Comment: The lack of a `p`, `n`, `µ`, or `m` in front of the `F` would be a hint

Comment: Some schematics don't have values, and are intended to give only a general idea of the system topology. So maybe I should just draw a really *large* capacitor symbol...

Comment: @StephenCollings Or the Superman "S" logo superimposed on the cap, might be culturally global enough to suffice ;-)

Comment: @AnindoGhosh I'd just finished this when you posted your comment! 
http://imgur.com/8SbNLXu

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A supercapacitor or Electric double-layer capacitor (EDLC) is functionally no different from a polarized capacitor, at the schematic level-of-abstraction. Hence, there is no standard symbol for it (yet), as distinct from the polarized capacitor symbol.

As with other schematic symbols, if there is a pressing need to indicate that a particular part on a design is a supercapacitor, that would be an annotation to the symbol.